# Weird behavior when passing object as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've got some code like the following (using discord.js, but that doesn't really matter in this question):

```
//in index.js
...
client.queues = {};
...
command.execute(message,args); //this will run the execute function of the command 'play'

//in play.js
module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  async execute (message,args) {
   ...
   const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
   message.client.queues[message.guild.id] = [args[0]];
   play(connection, message);
  ...
  }
}

function play(connection, message) {
 const song = message.client.queues[message.guild.id].shift(); //This gives a typeError, since message.client.queues is an empty object, even though I adjusted it in the execute function
 ...
}
```

As far as I know, the client object in index.js is the same as message.client in play.js.
I debugged the program and saw that, while still in the execute scope, client.queues succesfully gets adjusted, but as soon as I pass it as a variable to the play function, it's like it never got edited.
Does anyone have an idea why, and how I should tackle this?

Comment: Everything here looks fine, but you haven't given enough information about `message` or `args` in `index.js`. I can see that you initialized `client.queues` to an empty object but left out the step where you assign it to `message`. Not only that you haven't given any info about `message.guild.id`. Maybe give examples for `message` and `args` and we further debug this.

Comment: @saulmaldonado Thanks for the answer :) Indeed I didn't give a lot of debug info because I thought it was something Javascript-related, but it turns out it's some weird behavior in Discord.js itself, and I fixed it now.